# Trying Reading a file of ints and strings and getting errors

Tags: java, arraylist, java.util.scanner, parseint

I am Writing a program that will read a file of names and ages and then will sort them in ascending order. I am running into some problem which I think has to do with moving through the file and storing the ages and names in an array.

The file contains the entries like :
(56, Suresh) (89, Mahesh) (81, Shyam) (92, Vikas) (84, Shloka) (62, Nalini) (71, Ahbi)

I am using the below code to read the file :

```
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        Scanner inputFile = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("File to read from");
        File file = new File (inputFile.nextLine());
        inputFile = new Scanner(file);
        ArrayList<ponySort> nameAge = new ArrayList<ponySort>();
        String currentLine = inputFile.next();
        while (currentLine != null )
        {
            String [] text = inputFile.next().split(", ");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(text[0]);
            String name = text[1];
            nameAge.add(new ponySort(name, age));
            currentLine = inputFile.nextLine();
        }
        Collections.sort(nameAge, new Age());
        System.out.println(nameAge.toString());
    }
```

What I am looking for is to sort the names and ages then print them out in the correct order. 
But I am getting an error that looks like this after I put the file name in:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Suresh)"
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
>       at sortFile.main(sortFile.java:26)

Comment: read the doc. from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html : "The default whitespace delimiter used by a scanner is as recognized by Character.isWhitespace().". You might want to use `nextLine` instead.

Comment: Did you post the entire contents of your file? Does the file contain a single line of text? Or does the file contain multiple lines where each line contains a single name and age?

Answer (score 0):

The exact error you are getting when calling `Integer.parseInt` might be happening because you never stripped off the parentheses from the string number before attempting to parse it.

Assuming each input line would consist of one or more tuples looking like `(A, B)`, I would suggest the following:

```
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("File to read from");
File file = new File (inputFile.nextLine());
inputFile = new Scanner(file);
ArrayList<ponySort> nameAge = new ArrayList<ponySort>();

while (inputFile.hasNextLine()) {
    String currentLine = inputFile.nextLine();
    String[] parts = currentLine.split("(?<=\\)) (?=\\()");
    for (String part : parts) {
        String input = part.replaceAll("[()]", "");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(input.split(", ")[0]);
        String name = input.split(", ")[1];
        nameAge.add(new ponySort(name, age));
    }
}
```

The splitting logic I used takes a single line of one or more tuples, and splits on the space precisely located in between tuples (ignoring other spaces).  Then, we can remove the surrounding parentheses and use the same string splitting logic you were already using.

Note: Java naming convention says that classes should begin with an *uppercase* letter, so the name `PonySort` should be used instead of `ponySort`.

Comment: Ok so I did some did the changes that you suggested but I am still getting errors. This is the error that I am getting now  
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
 at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
 at sortFile.main(sortFile.java:26)
Would you have any clue why I am getting this? I tried changing the currentLine = inputFile.nextLine() at the bottom of my while loop to just currentLine = inputFile.next() but that also gave me an error.

Comment: @max Use `Scanner#hasNextLine()` to check if the scanner actually has another line.  If you call `nextLine()` and the scanner really has no more lines you will get a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: Have the hasNextLine() in their and everything is right, But am getting an error of:                     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
 at sortFile.main(sortFile.java:24)                                       Not sure what this is saying or how to fix it. it is a number format exception but says: for Input String: "".

Comment: It looks like you are trying to parse empty string into an integer, which obviously can't work.  As I think my code should be working now without error, I suggest that you take a look at your input data.

Comment: My input data being the file that I am reading? Looks just like this: (23, Rarity)(2000, Celestia)(50, Spike)(47, TwilightSparkle)(23, Fluttershy)(83200, RainbowDash)(23, AppleJack)(47, PinkiePie)(47, Scootaloo)(150, CheeseSandwich)  ... really not sure why I am getting these errors.

Comment: This disagrees with the sample data from your question, which clearly has a space in between tuples.  Just update my splitting logic to match whatever your real data is.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use custom delimeter for `Scanner` and read pair of `int` and `String`:

```
 final class PonySort {

    public static final Comparator<PonySort> SORT_AGE_ASC = Comparator.comparingInt(PonySort::getAge).thenComparing(PonySort::getName);

    private final String name;
    private final int age;
}

public static Set<PonySort> readFile(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(file)) {
        scan.useDelimiter("(\\)\\s+\\()|(,\\s)|\\(|\\)");

        Set<PonySort> nameAge = new TreeSet<>(PonySort.SORT_AGE_ASC);

        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            int age = scan.nextInt();
            String name = scan.next();
            nameAge.add(new PonySort(name, age));
        }

        return nameAge;
    }
}
```